# Requiring a module that requires itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an `index.js` file that looks a little bit like this:

```
exports.services = {
    service1: require("./service1"),
    service2: require("./service2"),
}
```

`service2` actually needs to make use of `service1`, though.  However inside of the `service2.js` file if I do:

```
var services = require("./").services
```

Then `services` will just be an empty object.  This makes some sense since `service2` is not completely required yet. Is there any way to give `service2` access to `service` without requiring it explicitly?

Comment: Why can't it require `./service1` directly?

Comment: @Scimonster it could, but there are other dependencies it could require as well and it would be useful to be able to cycle through these transparently rather than be explicit each time.  It's not a terrible solution, but I'm just checking if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in an object literal all at once, you could do it by setting the properties separately. This way, when it encounters the circularity, it will already have loaded some of it:

```
exports.services = {};
exports.services.service1 = require("./service1");
exports.services.service2 = require("./service2");
```

Warning: untested